# How to tell curl to use one client cert from the Windows Cert Store?

Tags: windows, curl, tls

Disclaimer: I am new to curl.

When I go to https://server.cryptomix.com/secure/ with Chrome, I am asked by Chrome to choose one client cert among the few ones I currently have in my Windows Cert Store.

[image: Chrome asks me]

Once I have choose a Cert, cryptomix.com is happy.

[image: cryptomix happy]

Fine. Now I have a curl shipped with Windows

```
c:\Windows\System32>curl --version
 curl 7.83.1 (Windows) libcurl/7.83.1 Schannel Release-Date: 2022-05-13 Protocols: dict file ftp ftps http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s smtp smtps telnet tftp Features: AsynchDNS HSTS IPv6 Kerberos Largefile NTLM SPNEGO SSL SSPI UnixSockets
```

BUT THEN, if I just curl https://server.cryptomix.com/secure/ cryptomix is NOT happy.

```
c:\Windows\System32>curl https://server.cryptomix.com/secure/
<html>
<head>
<title>TLS Client Authentication Test</title>

<style type="text/css">
  SPAN.sslsuccess {font-weight: bolder; color : green}
  SPAN.sslerror {font-weight: bolder; color : red}
</style>
</head>
<br><span class="sslerror">Error: No TLS client certificate presented</span>

</body>
</html>
```

How do I tell curl to use a certain client cert from my Windows Cert Store?

Comment: According to [SSL Certificate Verification](https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html), the certificate should be installed in *Start > Internet Options > Content > Certificates*.

Comment: @harrymc Sure. Thats where Chrome finds them and ask me to choose...

Comment: The link I gave was for curl, so it's supposed to work. Perhaps you could force it with the curl parameter `--cacert file` or `--cert`. Otherwise, perhaps curl doesn't like the certificate for some reason. You could debug the error using `curl -v`. Note from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36512510/165358): "It is not possible to connect to a TLS server with curl using only a client certificate, without the client private key".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using SCHANNEL (windows SSL) you [have to specify the path and thumbprint](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-E) of the target certificate.

> (Schannel only) Client certificates must be specified by a path
> expression to a certificate store. (Loading PFX is not supported; you
> can import it to a store first). You can use "<store
> name><thumbprint>" to refer to a certificate in the system
> certificates store, for example,
> "CurrentUser\MY\934a7ac6f8a5d579285a74fa61e19f23ddfe8d7a". Thumbprint
> is usually a SHA-1 hex string which you can see in certificate
> details. Following store locations are supported: CurrentUser,
> LocalMachine, CurrentService, Services, CurrentUserGroupPolicy,
> LocalMachineGroupPolicy, LocalMachineEnterprise.

Keep in mind you might have to escape backslash "\" characters in the path like "\\".

You can find the certificate thumbprint by navigating to the certificate in your store and going to the details tab:

[image]

Comment: OK! It works FINE WITHOUT "CurrentUser"!

Comment: Getting `curl: (58) schannel: Failed to get certificate location or file for CurrentUser\Personal\Certificates\...` Mind sharing the commandline you used?

Comment: @pointyhat I now use curl 8.0.1 2023-03-20 on Windows 11, but now you must again prefix with CurrentUser AND it does not work anymore! LOL `curl.exe --cert CurrentUser\\MY\\cdc8b933ade7942d0ff894b6c171f4987150ff9f https://server.cryptomix.com/secure/
curl: (35) schannel: AcquireCredentialsHandle failed: SEC_E_UNKNOWN_CREDENTIALS (0x8009030D) - The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized`